# Where could I have gone wrong with my imports?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a react web  app that I am building, a component is said to be likely forgotten to be exported. But when checking the code, the imports and exports seems fine

Since I am only working with dump components for now, I tried defining them different like using the fat arrow function but there was  no success.

Here is the snippet of for the Navbar- there SignIn and SignOut components are also declared in the same way as the navbar :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import SignInLink from './SignInLink'
import SignOutLink from './SignOutLink'

const Navbar = () => {
        return (
        <nav className="z-depth-10 black">
            <div className="nav-wrapper container">
                < Link to="/" className="brand-logo">Lelo's</Link>
                <SignInLink />
                <SignOutLink />
        </div>
      </nav>
        )
}


export default Navbar
```

After compiling, I get this from the browser:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports
```

Comment: did you export `SignInLink` and `SignOutLink` components as `default`?

Comment: Can you share the code inside `SignInLink` and `SignOutLink` components?

Comment: please share `SignInLink ` and `SignOutLink ` code!

Comment: Also, this: `< Link` is obviously wrong, how did this even compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to set `export default` in both components.

**SignInLink**

```
export default SignInLink
```

**SignOutLink**

```
export default SignOutLink
```

Can you please check it once. 

This will fix your issue.